# XCode : Find text within a function block

Tags: c++, xcode, find

Are there any way to search for a text in XCode within the enclosing function or class declaration block. This can be useful while diving in an unknown code especially when a particular variable name is expected but searching in whole file can be overwhelming.

I remember I used similar feature in Notepad++ (maybe VS also) long ago where we can select scope of search in the "find" dialogue box. I have been working on XCode since long and wonder if we can do similar thing.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Maybe split up your code into separate files

Comment: Not feasible in an existing code especially when working on decade old and huge code base. And moving out every function to it's own file will be an overkill.